# Regex Delete Everything Up To The First Period

Tags: regex

So this is something that has been playing on my mind for a while. I am a newbie to Regex. I know the basics but can't figure out how to put this regex together. Say I have the following

```
example1.keep.co.uk
example2.example3.keep.co.uk
example1.keep.me.uk
example2.example3.keep.me.uk
example1.keep.org.uk
example2.example3.keep.org.uk
```

In all the above examples I want to keep only keep.co.uk,keep.me.uk,keep.org.uk. Everything else should be stripped. I know I need to use .co.uk$|.me.uk$|.org.uk$. I want to say keep these but delete everything else to the left of the period. Any suggestions?

Comment: Just `^[^.]*\.` would be enough to be replaced with `""`

Answer (score 1):

```
.*?(keep.*$)
```

Try this.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/sA7pZ0/22

Comment: "keep" is a variable that has an unlimited number of combinations. How can I edit the regex to allow any number of characters and numbers in place of "keep"

Comment: what is constant then?is example1 example 2 constant?or last three dots are they constant?